# How to show that $ \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{i!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, binomial-theorem

In Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis (Indian Subcontinent Reprint of $3^{rd}$ Edition), while proving that  $ (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e $ (Theorem 3.31) Rudin states that:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n & = & 1+1+\frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) +\cdots+\frac 1 {n!}\left(1-\frac 1 n\right)\left(1-\frac 2 n\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac {n-1} n\right) \\
&=&  \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{i!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Rudin writes that this is expression comes from using Binomial Theorem, but does not elaborate further.
Applying the Binomial Theorem myself, I get
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n &=& 1 + {n \choose 1} \frac{1}{n} + {n \choose 2} { \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)}^2 + \cdots \\
  &=&   \sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i} 1^{n-i} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{i} \\
  &=& \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^i 
\end{eqnarray}
What next? How to proceed further?

Comment: Write the binomial coefficient as $\dfrac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$, and write $\dfrac{n!}{(n-i)!}$ as a product: $n(n-1)\cdots(n-i+1)$. Then insert into this the factors from $\dfrac{1}{n^i}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks, I get it now.